# Word for still being able to understand someone even when they use incorrect grammar?

Tags: grammar

I need some help... I've been trying to find a funny video I saw a while back that called out someone for correcting another's spoken grammar by using a term that basically meant that you can still understand what someone is saying even if proper grammar is not followed...

Does anybody remember what that term is or a link to the video?

Comment: “Intelligible”?

Comment: Maybe... It doesn't seem correct though from what I remember. Though this might work.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number from a table of numbers where the value needed is between two listed values the process is called *interpolation*. Using ratios you get to round-up or down as needed.

I use interpolation or say *interpolate* when I mean that the interpretation or meaning does not exist but I can get the meaning or gist from between the words they are using.

Comment: I see why you choose *interpolate* but *extrapolate* is probably closer to what is actually happening.

Comment: That kind of works. It isn't the term I'm thinking of though. It is directly related to the ability to understand language even though it isn't grammatically correct.

Comment: I would enjoy learning the word when you find it.